# Umbraco update from 7.2.8 to 7.12

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a site running on Umbraco 7.2.8 and it works perfectly, but I would like to update it to the latest version (7.12). The site runs perfectly, but when updating and entering `localhost:4123/umbraco` I can not log in with the following error "Login failed for user MyUser". Looking at the code and debugging note that it never calls the "ValidateUser" method that I have extended. What's going on? Thx!

```
public class TFAMembershipProvider : UsersMembershipProvider, ITFAMembershipProvider
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.UserService;

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        ... 
    }

    public IUser ValidateOneTimeCode(string username, string onetimecode)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="TwoFactorAuthentication.Package.Membership.BackOffice.TFAMembershipProvider, TwoFactorAuthentication.Package" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the logfiles? Is the user maybe locked out (check the umbracouser database table)?

Comment: Have you looked into umbraco version compare https://our.umbraco.com/download/releases/compare ?
are there any breaking changes?